# Javascript or jQuery to change navigation link class when scroll position is reached on main section

Tags: jquery, class, navigation, scroll

My page is a single page website which has a pageslide navigation on the side which has an id of "navigation". My main section is a fully fluid 100% wide design and it only changes when a button on the side is pressed to reveal the navigation menu. On this navigation menu, I want to be able to change the class of the links between two classes e.g "active" and "nonactive" and i want this to change depending on the position the user is scrolled at, i.e if the position the user is scrolled at is on the div id of "about", i want the class in the navigation that links to about to have a class of "active" and the rest of the links as "nonactive". This will be for every link.

My website is at http://sandbox.modernturtle.com

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Bootstrap has a plugin that does this for you. Here is a demo: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

**EDIT:**
Initialize the plugin like so:

```
$('#navigation').scrollspy();
```

Then add the `data-spy` attribute to the body tag:

```
<body data-spy="scroll" >...</body>
```

And at last (this step you already have on your site), match the navigation link's `href` to the div's `id`:

```
<a href="#about" onclick="$.scrollTo( '#about', 1000, {easing:''} ); CngClass(this);" class="selected">about</a>

<div id="about">
```

Comment: Hey that seems like the way to go, however, I have no idea on how to link it, would you mind helping me a little bit further? :)

Comment: Hey thanks for that mate, I actually managed to solve it a while ago, the problem was it wouldn't work to change the class of an 'a' tag, so I had to use unorganised lists and now it works great! :) Thanks again man.